# chmod 0775 is not changing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, file-permissions, chmod

I have an Ubuntu larval AWS instance running and I am trying to change some permissions:

When I visit my IP address for my newly installed site I get this warning:

```
The /var/www/seekadventure.net directory is not writable.
Please chmod this directory and its contents to 0775.
```

So in the command line I try this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-80-211:/var/www$ sudo chmod 0775 /var/www/seekadventure.net
ubuntu@ip-172-31-80-211:/var/www$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     4096 Dec 14 05:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Feb 27  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 28  2018 laravel5.6
drwxrwxr-x  5 root     root     4096 Dec 14 05:34 seekadventure.net
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Nov  8 13:32 utility
ubuntu@ip-172-31-80-211:/var/www$
```

And as you can see from the `ls -la` command its still `root root`

Any ideas why the permissions are not changing?

Update:

While doing further investigation I saw the mount command could show more useful information:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-80-211:/var/www$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=2014540k,nr_inodes=503635,mo                                                                                        de=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmod                                                                                        e=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404508k,mode=755)
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relat                                                                                        ime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xa                                                                                        ttr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu                                                                                        set)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hu                                                                                        getlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatim                                                                                        e,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                                                        ,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mem                                                                                        ory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,fr                                                                                        eezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,re                                                                                        latime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,de                                                                                        vices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blki                                                                                        o)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,time                                                                                        out=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
lxcfs on /var/lib/lxcfs type fuse.lxcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,grou                                                                                        p_id=0,allow_other)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404508k,mode=7                                                                                        00,uid=1000,gid=1000)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-80-211:/var/www$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `chmod` command to change file access permission such as `read(r)`, `write(w)` and `execute(x)`.

Use `chown` command to change file owner and group information.

if you want to change file access permission then try it :

`sudo chmod 777 /var/www/seekadventure.net`

4 stands for `read`.

2 stands for `write`.

1 stands for `execute`.

0 stands for `no permission`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while using kali linux on my raspberry pi even while using the superuser I couldnt change the persimmions I did reboot the system and bingo it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod -R 0775 /var/www/seekadventure.net
```